# Navigation & cache issue with ion-tab

Tags: angular, routes, tabs, ionic3, ionic5

I am having issue with cache & navigation, please look at screens.its simple tab app.

steps to generate issue.
initially its load home page.
then click on page1 link(used [navPush]=“page1” to navigate)
then click to contact tab
then click to home tab --> its shows page1(which is cached) and another point here any of the lifecycle events are not excuting[image]
then if you click home tab again it will work.

How to avoid this cache issue?

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: please let me know our ionic version .. may be you can print ionic info and share screenshot

Comment: Ionic:

   Ionic CLI : 6.16.2

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : not installed globally

System:

   NodeJS : v14.15.1
   npm    : 6.14.8
   OS     : macOS Big Sur

Comment: Are you still facing this issue

Comment: @TaylorRahul YEs, I am still facing the issue